# Sync PGP key with Ubuntu keyserver

Tags: pgp, keyserver

I tried to save my PGP public key on `keyserver.ubuntu.com`, but it didn't work.

I tried to save from the console and a web form. When I save from the web form, I get the error - `Unexpected POST request`. When I save from console, I don't have any errors.

I tried to create a PGP key from Ubuntu default program "Password and keys" and sync to server, that also didn't work.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Could you please add a little more detail? What *exactly* did you do, what did you expect to happen and what happened instead? Did you encounter any warning or error messages? Please reproduce them *in their entirety* in your question. You can select, copy and paste terminal content and most dialogue messages in Ubuntu. Please **[edit]** your post to add information instead of posting a comment. (see [How do I ask a good question?](/help/how-to-ask))

Comment: This is most likely an issue with the Ubuntu keyserver. I got the same error. I later tried http://keyserver.opensuse.org instead and it worked.

Comment: @DavidFoerster OP actually had posted all the relevant information. "Unexpected POST request" is literally *all* that the browser displays when trying to use the Ubuntu keyserver web interface, and doing it via `gpg` does silently fail.

Comment: @ace: I'm aware of that much. The missing piece is the (`gpg`?) command used to store the key file.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like it is a temporary issue with `keyserver.ubuntu.com` itself. I couldn't upload my PGP keys to it for a couple of days either. And currently, the signing key for a newly created PPA is not showing up there although more than four hours has already passed since the PPA creation.

Comment: Others are having the same problem with the PPA signing key. See https://answers.launchpad.net/launchpad/+question/670706 and https://bugs.launchpad.net/launchpad/+bug/1782354